# do you know any database design software supporting embedded documents (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, schema

I am trying to design a database schema for MongoDB but would like to be able to intuitively represent embedded documents. A bit like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/download/attachments/131465/reference.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1253899724083))</sub>

Does anyone know some software that lets me do this? I know I can do it on paper but I want to be able to share the schema with colleagues and have them edit small things.

Comment: Since MongoDB cannot store a schema database design tools are not common if at all exist, normally the design is application heavy as such database centric tools seem useless.

Comment: @Sammaye: While MongoDB has flexible schema, that does not completely remove the usefulness of designing an appropriate [data model](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) to support your application's common use cases. I think the question here could be addressed by a tool to _draw_ data models rather than _generate_ schema statements. With the original image link broken, it is hard to know what was intended .. but either way this "recommend a tool" question doesn't seem to be [on-topic for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Stennie of course I should probably have made it clear I was thinking more along the lines of application designers rather than say, MySQL tools since that is where the data model is defined and used.

Comment: @Stennie This refers to a tool for database design.Ye, MongoDB has flexible schema, but for a particular collection are defining certain rules: which fields can be? what type? optional or not? embeded documents etc.This question asks what instrument suitable for this design. Sure, JSON Schema suitable, but not so easy for leaning

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JSON Designer](http://www.jsondesigner.com/) for creating JSON modelling diagrams.  You could also consider using the [JSON Schema](http://davidwalsh.name/json-validation) format as a way to represent and share you Mongo document schema.